# Write stacks of GeoTIFF image to NetCDF by chunk size

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, netcdf, numpy

I converted GeoTIFF image stacks to NetCDF file with writing data by Index order (layer by layer) ([this was a main solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70458/convert-timeseries-stack-of-gtiff-raster-to-single-netcdf)).
The problem is, it writes slowly (for 25 images - 1Gb takes 90 seconds). One of the solution is to write the data chunk by chunk not the whole image at once.
Does somebody know how to do it or any other solution !?

Code (I used memory to keep images as much as possible then write them all at once)

```
def tiff_to_netcdf(imagesPath, output, chunksize=None):

    images = []
    for paths, subdirs, files in os.walk(imagesPath):
        for name in files:
            images.append(os.path.join(paths, name))

    ds = gdal.Open(images[0])

    a = ds.ReadAsArray()
    nlat, nlon = np.shape(a)

    b = ds.GetGeoTransform()  # bbox, interval
    lon = np.arange(nlon)*b[1]+b[0]
    lat = np.arange(nlat)*b[5]+b[3]

    basedate = dt.datetime(2006, 01, 11, 0, 0, 0)

    # Create NetCDF file
    # Clobber- Overwrite any existing file with the same name
    nco = netCDF4.Dataset(output+'.nc', 'w', clobber=True)

    # Create dimensions, variables and attributes:
    nco.createDimension('lon', nlon)
    nco.createDimension('lat', nlat)
    nco.createDimension('time', None)

    timeo = nco.createVariable('time', 'f4', ('time',))
    timeo.units = 'days since 2006-01-11 00:00:00'
    timeo.standard_name = 'time'

    lono = nco.createVariable('lon', 'f4', ('lon',))
    lono.standard_name = 'longitude'

    lato = nco.createVariable('lat', 'f4', ('lat',))
    lato.standard_name = 'latitude'

    # Create container variable for CRS: lon/lat WGS84 datum
    crso = nco.createVariable('crs', 'i4')
    crso.long_name = 'Lon/Lat Coords in WGS84'
    crso.grid_mapping_name = 'latitude_longitude'
    crso.longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0.0
    crso.semi_major_axis = 6378137.0
    crso.inverse_flattening = 298.257223563

    # Create short integer variable with chunking
    tmno = nco.createVariable('tmn', 'i2',  ('time', 'lat', 'lon'),
                              zlib=True, chunksizes=chunksize, fill_value=-9999)
    tmno.scale_factor = 0.01
    tmno.add_offset = 0.00
    tmno.grid_mapping = 'crs'
    tmno.set_auto_maskandscale(False)

    nco.Conventions = 'CF-1.6'

    # Write lon,lat
    lono[:] = lon
    lato[:] = lat

    pat = re.compile(r'^(\w{1})(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_\d{6}___SIG0.*.tif$')
    itime = 0
    written = 0
    data = np.empty((3, 8000, 8000), dtype=np.float)

    # Step through data, writing time and data to NetCDF
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(imagesPath):
        dirs.sort()
        files.sort()
        for f in files:

            match = re.match(pat, f)
            if match:

                if itime  % 3 == 0 and itime != 0:
                    tmno[written:itime, :, :] = data
                    written = itime
                # read the time values by parsing the filename
                year = int(match.group(2))
                mon = int(match.group(3))
                day = int(match.group(4))
                date = dt.datetime(year, mon, day, 0, 0, 0)
                print(date)
                dtime = (date-basedate).total_seconds()/86400.
                timeo[itime] = dtime
                tmn_path = os.path.join(root, f)
                print(tmn_path)
                tmn = gdal.Open(tmn_path)
                a = tmn.ReadAsArray()  # data
                data[itime%3, :, :] = a
                itime = itime+1


    nco.close()
```

Comment: Reading the whole image and then writing it should be faster than chunking it, unless the size of the image in memory exceeds that available for the process.   Is that the case?

Comment: @RichSignell I get memory error. Then I thought maybe to write them by chunks.

Comment: you could write in chunks, but to avoid the memory issue it seems you would have to read from geotiff in chunks as well.   I'm not sure you can do that.

Comment: @RichSignell can you show me how could I write in chunks !?, then I try to also read geotiff in chunks as well if it's possible !! - Thank you

Comment: just loop over an index.   E.g.   `tmno[itime, k, :] = data_band ` and loop over k

Comment: I think you've got some faulty logic here which could be giving your memory problems.  you just want to read the image using gdal and then immediately write to netcdf.  `a=tmn.ReadAsArray();             tmno[itime,:,:]=a`

Comment: @RichSignell Thanks for the code, I want to write them in timeseries, so I use this code which you provided it. otherweise gdal can convert it. am I right ?

Comment: Yes, you could use gdal to convert each geotiff to netcdf using `gdal_translate`.    But by using the python code you can use gdal to read each geotiff and add to a netcdf file with a time dimension.   If you don't have enough memory to read the entire geotiff, you could read each band and write each band to the netcdf file instead of each image all at once.

Comment: @RichSignell    I used `gdalvrt` to save all images in the separate band then load it. `ds = gdal.Open('images.vrt') / band1 = ds.GetRasterBand(1)  /  a = band1.ReadAsArray()`  --- I think what I did is different to what you mean ! then how could I write each band of geotiff !? _Sorry I do not have enough reputation to move it to chat. (if we have to)_