# Create multivariable NetCDF from several Raster files

Tags: raster, netcdf

Is it possible to create a NetCDF with several variables from a collection of rasters (same spatial bounds)?

I've tried the Arcpy tool [RasterToNetCDF](http://desktop.arcgis.com/es/arcmap/10.3/tools/multidimension-toolbox/raster-to-netcdf.html), but it seems thats it`s only able to transform one raster each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can find quite some information regarding **Creating multiband netcdf with GDAL**. Have a look [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70458/convert-timeseries-stack-of-gtiff-raster-to-single-netcdf). If that doesn't help, have a look at **gdal_merge.py**, once the individual rasters are created something like this should do

`gdal_merge.py image1.tif image2.tif image3.tif -o merged.nc`.